# i3wm stacking under thunar

Tags: i3

I am Using i3wm on Debian Jessie. I was wondering how to define the following behaviour:
When you open any file in Thunar (with  gedit, document viewer, etc), start stacking in the Thunar box i.e. this should cover the window with thunar and focus on the opened application.

Comment: I mean, the Thunar box should be always in "stacking mode"

Comment: Did you managed to get this done?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but it should definitely be a feature of i3